# Trying to get the status of mirrored databases using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to test the following script in powershell which gets the status of the mirrored databases.

```
#SQL Variables

$sqlservers = "APNSQL01"

#SQL database mirroring status

$body +=echo "------------Originating Server-----------"`r`n""`r`n""    
Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking

$body +=echo "--------Status of mirrored databases---------"`r`n""`r`n""
foreach ($server in $sqlservers){
    $body +=echo "Database mirroring state on $server

    "
    $body += Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "USE master
            SELECT sys.database_mirroring.mirroring_state_desc
                ,sys.databases.name
            FROM sys.database_mirroring INNER JOIN sys.databases ON sys.database_mirroring.database_id=sys.databases.database_id
            WHERE mirroring_state_desc IS NOT NULL" -ServerInstance "$server" | out-string

}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error :

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is
configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to
SQL Server)
At C:\Users\ctxadmin\Desktop\SQL.ps1:20 char:11
+     $body += Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "USE master
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
Invoke-Sqlcmd :
At C:\Users\ctxadmin\Desktop\SQL.ps1:20 char:11
+     $body += Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "USE master
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

My SQL server is a STANDARD database. It has no mirror. Is that the issue?
What might the error be?

Comment: so your using code designed for a mirrored database check against a DB with no mirror?  it's not going to work properly, the items you're selecting (`sys.database_mirroring.mirroring_state_desc`) don't exist and neither does `sys.database_mirroring` and `mirroring_state_desc` will be null if a value is returned at all.  what do you actually need to accomplish?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the SQL query, you just can't connect to the instance. Try: add -Database master to your Invoke-SqlCmd call. Check the name & permissions for each instance; are you connecting to a default or named instance? Are you running for multiple servers/instances? Cheers

Comment: @Mike Garuccio : Yaaa.. exactly.. I think that's the issue. I am asked to deliver reports regarding health checks of various environments. SQL mirrored environment is one of it.

Comment: so the code you have should work for a mirrored environment, but you'll need to create something else for non-mirrored environments.

Comment: Yaa....actually i need it only for mirrored environments. I dont have one. Are you sure about it? Like, not having a mirrored environment is the cause for my problems?

Comment: Those objects do exist even in non-mirrored instances so the query won't error. The error is clearly stating you can't connect to the instance itself, so it's not even getting as far as the query.